# group objects of list with the same reference in one object

Tags: java

I need to group objects of a list with the same reference in one object that has the same reference and whose `stud_locatio` field contains the concatenation of all the fields of the previous items.

```
public class Grouping {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {

    List<Entreprise> entlist = new ArrayList<Entreprise>();
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("11111", "logi", "New York"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("11111", "logi", "California"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("22222", "rafa", "Los Angeles"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("22222", "rafa", "New York"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("33333", "GR SARL", "LONDON"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("33333", "GR SARL", "LONDON"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("33333", "GR SARL", "italie"));
    entlist.add(new Entreprise("33333", "GR SARL", "Paris"));

    /*  Output should be Like below
        1111  :  logi : logi - New York
        22222 :  rafa : Los Angeles - California
        33333 :  GR SARL :   LONDON -  italie - paris */
}

class Entreprise {

    String reference;
    String stud_name;
    String stud_location;

    ENTREPRISE(String sid, String sname, String slocation) {
        this.ref = sid;
        this.stud_name = sname;
        this.stud_location = slocation;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like a homework assignment. It would be better if you mention what you've tried to do so far and what issues/errors you're getting

Comment: ... and probably best to quote the assignment too because you could have reworded it to mean something else..

Comment: For the first line, did you mean `1111  :  logi : New York - California`? Also what if there are multiple `sname`s for a given `sid`?

Comment: In what format do you want the output? Do you have a particular data structure in mind, or do you want to just print to the console?

Answer (score 0):

A way to do what you want is something like this

```
    // Grouping
    Map<String, Set<String>> group = new HashMap<String, Set<String>>();

    for (Enterprise enterp : entlist) {

        String key = enterp.getReference().concat(":").concat(enterp.getStud_name());
        String value = enterp.getStud_location();

        if (group.containsKey(key)) {
            group.get(key).add(value);
        }
        else {
            Set<String> stud = new HashSet<String>();
            stud.add(value);
            group.put(key, stud);
        }
    }

    // Printing
    for (String id : group.keySet()) {

        String locations = "";
        for (String stud : group.get(id)) {
            locations = locations.concat("-").concat(stud);
        }
        locations = locations.replaceFirst("^\\-", "");

        System.out.println(id + ":" + locations);
    }
```

The output is

```
22222:rafa:New York-Los Angeles
33333:GR SARL:Paris-italie-LONDON
11111:logi:California-New York
```